# WP Lumia 540 draining too Fast

Tags: windows-10-mobile, storage, battery, system-apps, battery-saver

My Lumia 540 is draining too quickly. It will be full at 6.00am then by 12.00 noon it is off. I have turned off apps running in the background. However the problem still persists. I have changed my battery three times in four months. What should I do for the phone to take at least 12 hours? It uses a Windows 10 OS

Comment: delete all unnecessary applications

Comment: How do I identify all unnecessary applications?

Comment: Are unnecessary applications the ones I do not use frequently?

Answer (score 0):

Try these [battery saving tips for Windows 10 Mobile](https://support.microsoft.com/en-ca/help/12388/windows-10-mobile-battery-saving-tips) provided by Windows Support